# Xdebug 3 works but throws errors in tests (docker)

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I have setup Xdebug for some remote debugging, and it works. Sadly it seems to break all of my tests.

This is the config:

```ini
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_port = 10001
xdebug.start_with_request = true
xdebug.idekey = mykey
xdebug.discover_client_host = true
```

[image: phpstorm]

I can connect just fine and step debug... but whenever I try running any PHP command on the CLI (tests for instance) I get this error for every single test (which makes all tests return an error):

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:10001 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

I am running this on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `xdebug.start_with_request = true` -- this is the reason. Configure Xdebug to NOT to attempt to debug every single script  See my comments here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/65616198/783119) as well as an answer from Xdebug author.

Comment: OR perhaps you want to debug and it does not work?

Comment: Sadly that stops my debugger from working. I have added an image of my phpstorm config as well. But thanks :)

Comment: So you are debugging a web page  .. or what? For a webpage debug -- you should also use Xdebug browser extension [Bookmarkets](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) (both set the Xdebug cookie telling "look, debug me"). I do not have `xdebug.start_with_request` line at all and it works fine this way for me.

Comment: What about PHP's `error_log` value? Xdebug uses PHP's error logging. The fact that such message is printed in your terminal output suggests that `error_log` is not configured properly (so PHP sends that to your STDOUT so you can see it). make sure to actually check the links in that question.

Comment: Check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide - there is no more config item 'idekey'
Try using XDEBUG_SESSION=mykey
You could also set xdebug.start_with_request to trigger.