# How can I hide a specific notice in PHP logs? (Xdebug)

Tags: php, logging, xdebug

I use Xdebug in PHP container. I regularly turn off the listener in PhpStorm. As a result 90% of my console consists of this Notice:

```text
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
```

What is the best way to avoid it? Hide or smth.

*Update:
Thanks to everybody for the answers. In the end, I did lower the error reporting level to warning. I think I’m gonna be fine with it. But maybe there is still a way to hide specifically this notice?

Comment: [try](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Configure Xdebug to NOT try to to debug every single request by default and only do it when needed. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65264131/783119