# Problems using Xdebug

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I'm new to using Xdebug. I followed the procedure indicated on the site xdebug.org.

PHP Version 8.0.9. I placed the `php_xdebug.dll` file in the "ext" folder.
Here are the lines I added to my php.ini file:

```ini
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

I then installed the extension in VS Code. I'm using the Edge browser.

Everything works fine when I start listening to Xdebug via my IDE. When I launch my page on the browser, the debugger works fine. However, when I refresh my page without starting Xdebug listening from my IDE, I get this PHP error:

> Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

How can I solve this problem?

I would like my browser not to call port 9003 if the Xdebug call is not in progress. I've tried modifying this line :

```
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger
```

This is rather restrictive because I had to install an Xdebug Chrome extension, which requires me to activate/deactivate Xdebug manually on the browser.

Comment: 1) *"I would like my browser not to call port 9003"* The browser does not do that. I strongly suggest you check the basics of how Xdebug works first, it will help you later. It's Xdebug that connects to the debug client (VSCode in your case) and NOT other way around.

Comment: 2) *"However, when I refresh my page without starting Xdebug listening from my IDE, I get this PHP error:"* That is expected / how Xdebug works ATM.  Because you have told it to do that with `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` and it simply tells you -- "I'm trying to debug but nobody is there, so I'm letting you know in case you have missed/misconfigured this". Perhaps some ideas from this answer help you -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65264131/783119

Comment: 3) *"This is rather restrictive because I had to install an Xdebug Chrome extension, which requires me to activate/deactivate Xdebug manually on the browser."* and it's the best solution -- click once when needed and another click when not. Easy.

Comment: Think about it. How can Xdebug know that you want a specific request step-debugged? You can either tell explicitly (`trigger`) or let Xdebug figure out if the IDE is listening (`yes`). If you wonder why it can't detect whether IDE is listening, well, that's what the timeout accomplishes. Is the message you shared showing up in some place where it's a problem?

Comment: You can also setup a debgpProxy that will always listen for Xdebug and VS Code will register with it when you start debugging. But that just "moves" notifications of IDE not being available from the PHP logs to dbgpProxy output. Unless you understand the core concepts of Xdebug/dbgp I don't advise you try this.